# short syntax to call array of functions using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I believe, there is a shorter way (one line) to write this using lodash:

```
  _.forEach(eventListeners, function(callback) {
    callback(event);
  })
```

... but can't find yet

Comment: @AndrewLi ES5 used there, no arrow functions...

Answer (score 16):

Lodash provides a utility function called `_.over` that returns a function that you can then call to pass some arguments to all of the functions you provided to `_.over`

[Official documentation for _.over](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#over)

```
var funs = [
  function(e) { console.log(e) },
  function(e) { console.log(e*2) },
  function(e) { console.log(e*3) }
];

_.over(funs)(10);
```

This will call all of the functions in the `funs` array with `10` as their argument, so in this case you should see in your console:

```
10
20
30
```

In your case specifically:

```
_.over(eventListeners)(event);
```